# AppSync Simulator: TypeError: Cannot convert undefined or null to object

Tags: serverless-framework, aws-appsync, serverless-offline, serverless-appsync-plugin

（I am using machine translation.sorry)

I'm building a local environment for appsync using a serverless framework

- Serverless-dynamodb-local
- Serverless-appsync-simulator
- Serverless-offline

I got an error when I installed these and used the "sls offline start" command

```
AppSync Simulator: TypeError: Cannot convert undefined or null to object
```

By the way, I'm using typescript instead of yml to create a project

```
//appsync
"appsync-simulator": {
  location: ".esbuild/.build",
  watch: false,
},

//dynamoDB
dynamodb: {
  stages: "dev",
  start : {
    port: 8000,
    inMemory: true,
  // migrate: true, 
  // seed: true, 
  }
},

//esbuild
esbuild: {
  bundle: true,
  minify: false,
  sourcemap: true,
  exclude: ["aws-sdk"],
  target: "node14",
  define: { "require.resolve": undefined },
  platform: "node",
  concurrency: 10,
},
```

schema.graphql is at the root
And this project works fine in the AWS Management Console

Team development requires offline
Please help me

Answer (score 4):

sorry, this issue has been resolved
It was a "serverless-appsync-simulator" and "cfn-resolver-lib" dependency issue

```
 "cfn-resolver-lib": "^1.1.8"　→　 "cfn-resolver-lib": "^1.1.7"
```

Downgrade “cfn-resolver-lib”

Thanks guys！

Comment: That does not help, btw. Semver "^1.1.7" includes 1.1.8. Better use a locked version without a prefix here. `"cfn-resolver-lib": "1.1.7"`